# Determine class type in C++ without reflection/introspection

Tags: c++, templates, types, static

I have an interface class called A and two base classes B and C that implement A.  In my code I sometimes need to determine if an instance is either B or C and I would prefer to not have a local non-static member of A that determines if the implementing class is of type B or C.  For performance reasons I also would not like to use dynamic_cast or other forms of reflection to determine their type.

Would it be advisable to make a base class AA for A that takes a template argument of type int and use that value to determine the type of B or C?

Or how about defining a static method in A that returns an enum type that is shadowed by similar methods in B and C?

Answer (score 1):

Every time I have such a dilemma I use visitor pattern.

**EDIT:**

In your case, you would have to add to A:

```
virtual void visitMe(IVisitor *) = 0;
```

Then In each of classes implement it like this:

```
void B::visitMe(IVisitor *visitor)
{
    visitor->visit(this);
}
```

In your visitor class you should add "visit" function for each of types:

```
struct Visitor: public IVisit
{
    void visit(B *);
    void visit(C *);
}
```

As you have different visit functions for each of types, you can recognise which type you are using by calling:

```
Visitor visitor;
C item;

item.visitMe(&visitor);    //visit for C will be used
```

Comment: Can you explain?  Not sure how it will help.

Comment: @stgtscc: I've added an example

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to avoid virtual functions in general? In that case, you can add that functionality to A itself:

```
struct A {
    enum ClassType { ClassTypeB, ClassTypeC };
    const ClassType mClassType;

    ClassType classType() const
    { return mClassType; }

protected:
    A(ClassType type) : mClassType(type) { }
};
```

In the child classes you would then initialize A with something like:

```
struct B: public A {
    B() : A(ClassTypeB) { }
};

struct C: public A {
    C() : A(ClassTypeC) { }
};

// ...

A* obj1 = new B;
A* obj2 = new C;
obj1->classType() == A::ClassTypeB; // true
obj2->classType() == A::ClassTypeC; // true
```

This lets you avoid any virtual method dispatch, but the drawback is that `A` must now have knowledge of its child classes.

Comment: I like this approach.. is it perhaps better to template ClassType?  Wouldn't it save 4 bytes per object?

Comment: To answer your question, yes I'm trying to avoid as much overhead as possible.

Comment: @stgtscc I must admit that I'm not sure how to template this, since declaring pointers to `A` would require you to list the type template argument. For example: `A<ClassTypeB>* obj1 = new B;`. Since then you already know the type, there's no reason to have the mechanism at all.